# css transition not functioning with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a css transition effect to an element as below:

```js
$('.trans-opener').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 3).toggleClass('trans-hidden');
});
```

```css
.row{
  padding: 50px;
  }
.trans-hidden {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li .icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <ul>
            <li class="trans-opener"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the (...) three dots icon, the other icons appear. But I'm trying to give transition effect to the icons. I tried `transition: all 0.3s;` but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciable.

http://jsfiddle.net/nwy333pe/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are making them dissappear/reappear by toggling `display:none;`. Display is not an `animatable` property (http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/)

Comment: How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can achieve that much easier with jQuery `fadeIn()` function, like this:

```js
$('.trans-opener').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 3).fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.row{
  padding: 50px;
  }
.trans-hidden {
    display: none;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    right: 15px;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li .icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <ul>
            <li class="trans-opener"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want them to unfold (i.e. move right), you need to specify the location for each of them individually. Try this:

```js
$('.trans-opener').click(function () {
  var icons = $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 3)
  if(icons.is(":visible")){
    $(icons).animate({right: 60}, function(){ icons.toggle(); });
  }
  else{
    icons.toggle();
    $(icons[0]).animate({right: 200});
    $(icons[1]).animate({right: 150});
    $(icons[2]).animate({right: 100});
  }
});
```

```css
.row{
  padding: 50px;
  }
.trans-hidden {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li .icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <ul>
            <li class="trans-opener"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div></a>

            </li>
            <li class="trans-hidden"><a href="#"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it doesn't close on clicking again.

Comment: If you want it to toggle, then use `fadeToggle()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This works, but I was trying for something in which the icons moves from right to the left.

Comment: You need to describe your requirements clearly in your question, so can help you without having to go back and forth between the comments. See my updated answer, I think the second code gives you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyframes, for making icons animatable, first you must set display:block in early step of animation. For fadeIn animation you can use.

```
ul li .icon {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-color: #cdcdcd;
        line-height: 35px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: fadeInCustom 1s;
    }

@keyframes fadeInCustom {
        0% {
            display: none;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        1% {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        100% {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
        }
}
```